# Calculate average of values in a column based on matches of two variables in two other columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having an issue with some data that I'm working on that has had me stuck for a while.

I'm working on some patient data for a clinical practice that has each patient encounter logged on a separate line with an account ID, date of service, the height and weight measurements for that date, and other variables.

Aside from `VLOOKUP` and the usual formulae/functions I've got a pretty rudimentary understanding of Excel but I can pick up on things fairly quickly.

In the data I've got each line tied to a patient account ID as well as what quarter the DOS was in. For patients with multiple visits, they will be identifiable by repetitions of the account ID number on other lines.

For some patients, there will also be repetitions in the quarter if the same patient was seen twice in the same quarter. This is where I need help.

I'd simply like to average the value of a variable for each patient in each quarter. I'm not sure if `AVERAGEIFS` is the right function to use but I need an operation that checks for matches in a line of both account ID and quarter (Q1, Q2, Q3, or Q4) with the other lines in the sheet and comes up with a quarterly average for the variables in question.

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qmlus.png)

[What I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdeUY.png)

Comment: Hi Andres, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55363923/edit) the title of your question to be more descriptive, and please don't include any time-related verbiage like "ASAP". As for your question - can you please provide some sample data, some input/output, or a screenshot of your table setups?

Comment: It would probably help to use a table to include a mockup (no actual patient data, of course) of the various columns that you're looking to act on.

Comment: Hi Adam, Thanks so much for the feedback. I've updated my post above with the information detailing what I have as well as what I'm looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

I used the function:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$13="Customer 1")*($C$2:$C$13="Q1"))
```

Where `Customer 1` could be a user id and `Q1` you can change to which quarter you want.

[Excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmjxn.png)

Comment: Hi Krysteel, thanks so much for your help. I'm away from the spreadsheet currently, so I'm just confirming, Will this average all the values for a particular variable that match in ID and Quarter? That's my main objective.

Comment: No, this will add up the total quarters for each user id.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question, you could use AVERAGEIFS to accomplish what you are asking.  With excel, a lot of how successful an approach will be is determined by how your data is structured, and if/how often you are planning on updating your work.
It would be easier to give a concrete answer with an example of the data you are looking at.

If your source data is in columns A:D something like:

[image]

and you are looking to summarize the weight data in I by account ID and Quarter:

[image]

you could use AVERAGEIFS(C:C,A:A,G2,B:B,H2) this would find the cells in column A that match the value in G2, find the cells in column B that match the value in H2, and report the mean value in column C of the matching rows.

An alternative is to use a pivot table, which automates a lot of what you are trying to do.  For that approach you would select your data block, and click on Insert>>Insert Pivot Table (at least in my version).  That should bring up a wizard.  Accepting the defaults will create a new sheet.  Then look on the right side of your window, and you should see a list of your column names near the top, and four boxes called Filters, Columns, Rows, and Values.  You should be able to drag and drop your columns into these boxes to get summaries of your data.  If you add your Account ID and Quarter tabs as columns, and your height and weight as Values, then right click on each of the value columns and select "Value Field Settings" and select Average from the menu that pops up.  That should give you something that looks like:

[image]

At that point, you can change the formatting to make if fit your needs, or copy data somewhere else.

The AVERAGEIFS approach will automatically update if you add more data, but will only summarize things that match the values you list.  If there is an account ID/Quarter pair that isn't in the summary column you won't have any idea it's there.  If you are summarizing an ID/Quarter pair that isn't in your data you'll end up with a division by Zero error like in the example.

The Pivot Table option only updates when you manually click refresh (right click and choose refresh pivot table from the menu), but will summarize all the data based on the columns you've selected.  It's also a little more robust as you avoid having to type out the formulas and make sure you are pointing to the right column.  This option also by default provides nested summaries; you can turn the subtotals and grand totals off if you want.

Comment: Hi Brian, I want to thank you for all the time and effort you put into helping me. You've really cleared things up a lot. I'm sorry to continue to bother you, but is there any particular way I could get work the data in the way shown above? I've updated my question with screenshots of what I have and where I'm trying to get to.

Comment: Use the AVERAGEIFS approach.  Add a row above your titles that has the Q1, Q1, Q2, Q2, etc starting above "Q1_Wt".  Then in the portion of the formula that refers to the quarter, use an absolute row reference (eg E$1) as the match criteria.  I would also use absolute column references for all of the ones pointing back to your original data set.